# filter the most recent line, basing on the date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

Hi i am using this query to select article belonging to a entity based on the most recent date:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ld.artigo, 
                cd.data, 
                cd.entidade, 
                cd.tipodoc, 
                cd.numdoc 
FROM   cabecdoc AS cd 
INNER JOIN linhasdoc AS ld 
        ON cd.id = ld.idcabecdoc 
INNER JOIN cabecdocstatus AS cds 
        ON ld.idcabecdoc = cds.idcabecdoc 
WHERE  cd.tipodoc = 'FAR' 
       AND ld.artigo IS NOT NULL 
       AND cds.estado <> 't;r' 
ORDER  BY cd.data DESC
```

Let's asume that i have this result

```
Artigo  Entidade         Data
Tr01    002              10-07-2015
Tr01    003              9-10-2015
Mn09    001              11-12-2016
Jk90    009              12-07-2016
Tr01    012              4-09-2016
```

The result i am looking for is this:

```
Artigo                   entidade                             data
Mn09                      0001                                  11-12-2016
Jk90                      0009                               2-07-2016
Tr01                      0012                               4-09-2016
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a windowed `ROW_NUMBER()` function with a `PARTITION` on the `artigo` to determine which one is the most recent, and only pull those results.

```
;With Cte As
(
    SELECT ld.artigo
        ,cd.data
        ,cd.entidade
        ,cd.tipodoc
        ,cd.numdoc
        ,Row_Number() Over (Partition By ld.artigo Order By cd.data desc) As Seq
    FROM CabecDoc AS cd
    INNER JOIN LinhasDoc AS ld ON cd.id = ld.IdCabecDoc
    INNER JOIN CabecDocStatus AS cds ON ld.IdCabecDoc = cds.IdCabecDoc
    WHERE cd.TipoDoc = 'FAR'
        AND ld.Artigo IS NOT NULL
        AND cds.Estado <> 't;r'
)
Select  artigo, entidade, data
From    Cte
Where   Seq = 1
```

Comment: what about the `DISTINCT` ?

Comment: I'd assume he wouldn't need the `DISTINCT` operation if he's only taking the top item per group.

Comment: Ok, even if there are duplicates rows on same date, one will be 1 and the other 2. So doesnt change result

Answer (score 0):

Use your result query as base to create a new one

```
 SELECT Artigo, Entidade, Data
 FROM (  
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Artigo ORDER BY Data DESC) as rn
        FROM YourQuery YQ
      ) T
 WHERE T.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using window functions as below

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT DISTINCT ld.artigo, 
                cd.data, 
                cd.entidade, 
                cd.tipodoc, 
                cd.numdoc 
FROM   cabecdoc AS cd 
INNER JOIN linhasdoc AS ld 
        ON cd.id = ld.idcabecdoc 
INNER JOIN cabecdocstatus AS cds 
        ON ld.idcabecdoc = cds.idcabecdoc 
WHERE  cd.tipodoc = 'FAR' 
       AND ld.artigo IS NOT NULL 
       AND cds.estado <> 't;r' 
), CTE1 AS
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Artigo,entidade order by data desc) as RN
FROM CTE
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE1 
WHERE rn = 1
```

The code can be further refined based on your exact needs